# Symfony2 loop redirect after logout

Tags: symfony, pdo

I have loop redirect after logout

My security.yml

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager # Use form.csrf_provider instead for Symfony <2.4
#                login_path: /login111
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true




    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/accaunt, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/accaunt/, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/,               roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
        - { path: ^/_wdt, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/_profiler, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

If I'm replace in config.yml     handler_id: session.handler.pdo
into handler_id:  ~

All good

Comment: where are you redirected?

Comment: After you logout, you are being redirected to default page. In your case that's probably `/` which is protected by full authenticated role - thus the redirect. Could that be the issue?

Comment: @JovanPerovic: I can bet on it. For this reason I was asking to what page he wa redirected

Comment: Also, please show us your `config.yml`. If this has anything to do with `session.handler.pdo` we will see it right there...

Comment: loop redirect to /login

Comment: session.handler.pdo:
        class:     Games\FirstBundle\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\UserIdPdoSessionHandler
        arguments: ["@pdo", "%pdo.db_options%",@security.context]

Comment: and if delete cookie PHPSESSID. Loop redirect stoped

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests, when an anonymous user try to access page A which needs an admin role, symfony redirects to the login page, login page of your seems to be also aking for a role user, and hence the error

I think your problem is a typo?! the ^/login$ in your access_control?

Comment: if delete this line the problem remains

Comment: no not delete the entire line, change it to just ^/login

Comment: if change it's the problem keep

Comment: after logout and visit the home page "/" they redirect to /login where loop redirect

Comment: like those other guys who mentioned it before me, did you change the 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY' role and check?

Comment: if - { path: ^/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY } have loop

Comment: if visit /login we get loop

Comment: I change session handler into redissesion and problem resolv

Comment: can you explain the reason for this? why was that happening?